# how to add bound to clustering algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I've got a numeric matrix with 72 rows and 2 columns where the first column is the index value and the other column has sequence from 0 to 5 repeated 12 times.  The dataset is like above:

```
1  0  
2  1  
....  
6  5   
7  0  
.... 
72 5
```

I add the dataset graph
[image]

I would like to use machine learning with a clustering algorithm to group data in 6 clusters horizontally. How to force algorithm to consider only nearest values on the x axe? How to modify the dataset to force the algorithm to consider this bound? 
How to obtain a solution like below?
[image]

Comment: If you want it to cluster using only the value of the x-coordinate, only let the clustering algorithm see the x-coordinate and not the y-coordinate.  But in this case if it only needs to work for this one dataset, you don't need a clustering or machine learning algorithm -- just output that one pre-determined set of clusters.  Both of those answers seem so straightforward that I suspect I must not be understanding what you are asking.  Can you edit the question to make it clearer what problem you are trying to solve, what approaches you've already considered, and why you rejected them?

Comment: thank you for the comment. The dataset above is an example. The dataset I'm using has recurrent pattern that values grows until a value then go down, grow again, an so on... and I would like to "teach" to the algorithm to return contiguous values. But now it returns, for example, cluster 1 = 1,2,3,5,45,46,77,80.

Comment: I suggest you provide in the question a specification of what properties you want the solution to have.  A single example is not a substitute for a description of what properties you want it to have in general.  I confess I don't understand what it means for a value to go down or grow, so I currently don't understand what you are trying to achieve.  I encourage you to use this feedback to help you figure out how to edit the question to improve it.  Thanks!

Comment: You can cluster into the 12 "natural" groups by using DBSCAN with a radius that includes adjacent "diagonal" points but doesn't include large jumps and a min points value of 1. However the groups you want don't strike me as natural in any sense. Also clustering algorithms are for _discovering_ clusters: if you already know what clusters you want, just take them, don't run an algorithm.